# Polymer 2.x. Firefox/Edge. Adding style element to shadow dom leaks to main document

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Using Polymer 2.x, I have an apparent problem that if I have a custom element which appends a  element to the custom elements' local dom then the css is incorrectly applied to the main document when running firefox or edge, but is fine in chrome.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/webcomponents+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  Click Test and this text will go red in firefox/edge<br>

  <my-element>
  </my-element>

  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <button on-click="handleClick">Test</button>
      <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'my-element' }

        handleClick() {
          var e = document.createElement('style');
          e.textContent = "* {color: red}";
          Polymer.dom(this.$.wrapper).appendChild(e);
        }
      }

      customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
    });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer http://jsbin.com/tizazadebe/edit?html,output

Is adding a <style> element to local dom supported like this?

Comment: Why don't you add CSS the normal way instead, with either creating an CSS class in your custom element and then toggle it with `this.toggleClass` or use `this.$.wrapper.style.color`?

Comment: Because this component is actually about allowing (trusted) html pages to be embedded within the main document.  And those pages can contain <style> blocks.

Comment: Interesting. I've spent some time testing this behavior and I got the same result. It seems to me to be a bug on IE. Sorry I can only recommend you to open a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: By the way, in Polymer 2 is no longer necessary to use Polymer.dom API. Just use `this.$.wrapped.appendChild(e);`

Comment: @jfcorugedo the problem may well affect IE.  I don't know.  But the question itself says the problem affects firefox and edge.  Out of those, firefox support is my main aim.  I do not expect this to be a browser bug as such, rather a problem with the applicable polyfill.
Agreed, Polymer.dom is unrequired in 2.x.